# How to make a company about video

Tags: html, flash, video, drawing

I would like to make videos like www.commoncraft.com . They are pretty amazing for how simple they are...They accurately show what the company or service does. They did Google Doc's Videos and a lot of other companies videos. How would I create these. I know flash but what else and what skills would I need to have to accomplish making these?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about creating a video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Adobe CS you have all necessary software. not skills but some steps:

- find idea for the video.
- doodling/sketching on the paper all screens of you future video.
- recreate previous step on the computer (it fast to draw using something like wacom bamboo).
- you will need some software for audio recording (Audacity free and easy to use).

mostly people stuck on the first two steps.

Comment: Most people probably go nuts while trying to complete the first step ;)